# How to fix "Could not make numeric conversion for modulo" error in xhtml code

Tags: xhtml

How to fix the below error in my xhtml file.

> ```
> Error: 
> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>   - Could not make numeric conversion for modulo 
>    operation
>   - Syntax error in EL
>   - This equals will always results a value of false
> ```

Below is the line of my code:

```
rowStyleClass="#{count.lineNo == 'Totals' or count.coolCar ? 'totalStyle' : empty rowIndex or rowIndex mod 2 ne 0 ? 'odd-row' :'even-row'}"
```